# PHP and mysql how to use joins to get the desired result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

When using Mysql and Php,

I have always done single queries and then used foreach loops to build an array of results from mysql databases. What id like to find out is how to do this with mysql instead.

My question is simple but im not sure how to go about it.

Basically id like to join 2 or more tables and end up with something like this:

['match from table 1'][0,1,2,3,4]

where table 1 is the main table and 0,1,2,3,4 are the results from the join.
at the moment i keep getting results in this format when doing joins

['table1'][0]
['table1'][1]
['table1'][2]

Basically what is happening is that I have 2 tables,
Hotels and Rooms. When i join them i get the same hotel name with 1 room,
My next result is then the very same hotel name with the next room...

What id like is for each hotel to return 1 result with all the rooms packed into the array. I have never understood how to achieve this with only a mysql query.

Ps. I did my undergrad (but sql was always my weakest point)
I am now considering doing a short sql brush up online course over my December break. So if you would like to chip in and point me to a good one id appreciate that.

Thanks!

Comment: Either use `RIGHT JOIN` or switch the tables around so it matches hotels to rooms. I'm not that deep into SQL but it seems in this case it's better to do a foreach loop on the hotels and retrieve the rooms. Unless there is a very specific reason not to.

Comment: ok so i tried a right join as such: SELECT * FROM vendor v RIGHT JOIN accomodation_room ar ON v.id=ar.vendor_id  But i still end up with multiple results coming back with the same hotel ie: ['hotel1']['room1']   then ['hotel1']['room2'] instead of just ['hotel1'][0,1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I`m getting you right you want sql query which will return associative array like this:

```
[hotel1] => [
             0 => room1,
             1 => room2
             ..........
...........
];
```

SQL doesn`t work like that. It returns whole rows of data. If there is one result in the left table that is linked to many others in the right table, depending on the SELECT query you will most probably have repeating rows of data from the left table and its related data in the right table.
The way you can achieve multi array (that I mentioned above) is by iterating the result in php and modify it like you want.

I edited my answer with a solution that I forgot about. I`m not sure if it is going to help you:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2Result.implodedField2 FROM table1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, table1Id, GROUP_CONCAT(field2 SEPARATOR ', ') AS implodedField2 FROM table2 WHERE table1Id=:table1Id
) AS table2Result ON table2Result.table1Id=table1.id
WHERE table1.id=:id
```

table1Id - is the column in table2 which is used for link to table1 (in your case this is may be hotel_id in table hotel_rooms)
The problem is that you have to pass the exact table1 id (hotel_id) to get its results.
This query should return one result from table1 and the concatenated results (for given column) from table2. It will be normal one dimension array in php :)

Comment: i just thought perhaps there was a way to get an associative array from a query. i have been using PHP to iterate the results and build the array. guess ill keep doing that.

Comment: You can do it all in one loop with the query to simplify things.